# Vue.js - Emit event from child to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am not able to `$emit` an event from a child component to it's parent.
I can successfully send the event, but not receive it in the parent.

`Results.vue` (**Child**):

```
<a href="#" v-on:click="sendResultValues"></a>

// 

methods: {
    sendResultValues: function () {
        this.$emit('send-result-values', 'carrier');
    }
},
```

When I click on the `<a>`, I can see with Vue DevTools that an `$emit` event is fired:

[image]
However, nothing is received in the console.log as my code below (parent):

`Input.vue` (**Parent**):

```
<search-results></search-results> //Results.vue component
<search-popover v-on:send-result-values="showResultData"></search-popover>
 //
methods: {
    showResultData: function () {
        console.log("Data received from child: ")
    }
 },
```

Comment: Is `results.vue` the component for `search-popover` or is `results.vue` part of `search-popover`?

Comment: In my `Input.vue` (**Parent**) file I have these two components: `<search-results></search-results>` and `<search-popover></search-popover>`

Comment: dunno, seems to work. https://codesandbox.io/s/0pwz408prp Edit the sandbox so it's more similar to your actual vue

Comment: Well, you need to listen on the event on the `<search-results></search-results>`, not on the `<search-popover></search-popover>`

Comment: You're setting the handler on search-popover but the one who emits the event is search-result as seen in the image

Comment: @Hammerbot - Ah! Thanks!! Now it works. Would you mind submitting this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to listen to the event on the `search-results` component, not on the `search-popover`.

Input.vue (Parent):

```
<search-results v-on:send-result-values="showResultData"></search-results>
<search-popover></search-popover>

methods: {
    showResultData: function () {
        console.log("Data received from child: ")
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should do the event declaration equation on the parent side.

you are wrong on :
`<a href="#" v-on:click="sendResultValues"></a>`

the click event shouldn't be that, it should be send-result-values. So the result is

`<a href="#" v-on:send-result-values="sendResultValues"></a>`

Comment: Your answer should be in English. Please do not attempt to show two versions of an answer, you already had differences in there and they would grow worse if people would attempt to help you with your formatting, which you also did not get clean. Feel free to double check and [edit] in case that I broke anything.